# Best way to Integrate Google Search?

Tags: search, google-search

I would like to use Google Search as opposed to the built-in search provided by the WordPress engine. What would be the best way to integrate Google Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of plugins that provide this functionality:

- **[Google Custom Search Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-custom-search-for-wordpress/)**
- **[Google Ajax Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-ajax-search/)**